# How to write a generalized method in Factory Pattern to provide object?

Tags: java, android, generics, factory-pattern

```
public class GsonStudentFactory{
....
 public static MasterStudent createMasterStudent(Student student) {
    return gson.fromJson(student.getBody(), MasterStudent.class);
 }

 public static  BTechStudent createBtechStudent(Student student) {
    return gson.fromJson(student.getBody(), BTechStudent.class);
 }
...
}
```

In order to generalize I can use 'if' condition and I can check 'if instance of student is BTechStudent or MasterStudent' and return appropriate BTechStudent or MasterStudent object.

Is there any better way, to generalize these two methods?

note:- BTechStudent and MasterStudent classes extends Student class.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood it correctly, but see if this helps you:

```
public static <T extends Student> T createStudent(Student student) {
    return gson.fromJson(student.getBody(), (Class<T>) student.getClass());
}
```

And use it like this:

```
MasterStudent masterStudent = createStudent(student);
```

or

```
BTechStudent btech = createStudent(student);
```